# Is it safe to save password in $.ajaxSetup()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am connecting to a server that has basic authentication and does multiple ajax on different parts of the page. Is it safe to setup the password in the ajaxSetup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
   username:        _username,
   password:        _password,
   timeout:         this.dmDuration,
   headers: {
      "Authorization": 'Basic ' + btoa(_username + ':' + _password) }
 });
```

Comment: You are making ajax call to your own server or a third party server?

Comment: @SankalpBhatt Even if it is to a 3rd party. The request should be made server side with the password secured in compiled code and the connection made through https. Never ever place a password client side under any circumstance!

Comment: @Nick Yeah! you are correct but you are not providing solution to the problem. I want to provide him with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not safe to place the password client side.

Can be intercepted or even read in plain text as simply as reading the request packet. Not a smart idea. You should store the password server side.

Even if the request is to a 3rd party product, the password should be secured in server side code and the request to the 3rd party should be through a secured connection from the server side. That way only the developer who wrote the code knows the password and it can never be seen and possibly distributed by end users or hackers.

If you are writing to a 3rd party then write the ajax setup to send a request to your server side function. This server side function containing the password will then send a secured request to the server without the password ever being seen.

If you are to make a ajax call locally, perhaps to authorize the call. You should first authenticate the user server side and on success develop a secure session for the user and a cryptographically unique anti CSRF token. From then on, every call should be made from the authenticated user, but the CSRF token must be passed on any ajax call to make sure the call has in fact been submitted by the user and not from a potential CSRF attack.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not safe.

Most of serve side platforms will allow you to define a session (usually a session token is provided to the client and passed back using a cookie). Once you open the session you won't need the password for the next calls.

I.e. in .net you can use [WCF session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) aware services.